# Memory Errors when reading the file in utf-8 format

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I have a 1GB json file and i want to parse it using simplejson in python. So i wrote a simple code as below which works fine

```
import simplejson
f=open('stem.json','r')
content=f.read()
data=simplejson.loads(content)
```

The problem with the above code is that it does not read data in 'utf-8' format

So i rewrote the code as below

```
import simplejson 
import codecs
f=codecs.open('stem.json','r',encoding='utf-8')
content=f.read()
data=simplejson.loads(content)
```

The problem with the above code is it wont execute, kernel is "Killing" the program.

I feel this problem is strange because without encoding it works and when i try to read it with encoding it takes lot of memory

Can anyone tell me whats happening here ?

Comment: 1GB of JSON?  Chances are a different persistence mechanism is more  appropriate here.  How about using a database?  The `MemoryError` simply means you are running out of memory.

Comment: Yeah, but why MemoryError only when i am using a different encoding Thanks for the reply

Comment: It isn't really surprising that decoding the string to a `unicode` object consumes additional memory.

Comment: Yeah, i might have to change the way i am going to read the file but i am not sure how to do it which works with the encoding

Comment: Which line causes out of memory condition? Can you load JSON directly from file instead of using an intermediate string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to open the file normally and use [`simplejson.load()`](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#simplejson.load) with an `encoding` parameter instead of reading the whole file into memory first:

```
with open("stem.json", "r") as f:
    data = simplejson.load(f, encoding="utf-8")
```

As I said in the comment above, I think the real solution is to use a different persistence backend, other than serialising to JSON.

Comment: Yes, it works as you said. Thanks for the answer but as you said i need to move to a persistence backend than JSON. The thing is that i have the big file properly structured in JSON format, it is the reason why i serialise it to JSON